# Add col to the colgroup of html table in run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  define the table with the following code snippet.

```
<div class="gridheadercontainer">
        <table class="table" cellspacing="0">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 150px;">
                <col style="width: 150px;">
                <col style="width: 150px;">
                <col style="width: 150px;">
                <col style="width: 150px;">
            </colgroup>
           <thead>
           <tr class="columnheader" style="cursor: pointer;">
               <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Task name</div></th>
               <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Start time</div></th>
               <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">End time</div></th>
               <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Duration</div></th>
               <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv">Status</div></th>
               <th class="headercell"><div class="headercelldiv"></div></th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody class="hide"><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

In this case I have use the following code snippet to append the col to the colgroup of table.

```
$('.gridheadercontainer table colgroup').prepend(doc.createElement('col'));
```

But it will add the column in the 0th index.
How to the col to the last of the colgroup table

Answer (score 1):

You mean [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('.gridheadercontainer table colgroup').append(doc.createElement('col'));
```

Comment: thank thank you for your reply , I have tried the provided code . but still i have face the same problem it did not add to the last index of colgroup

Comment: @Raja can you share your script

Comment: Hi Thank  you in simple html it's working fine . I will check my implementation. Thank You